# KSOAP2 connection without IP address hardcoded

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

```
private String METHOD_NAME = "schedule";
private String NAMESPACE = "http://calculate.backend.web.org";
private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME; 
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.4:8080/AndroidBackEnd/services/Calculate?wsdl";
```

This the code I am using to connect to my web-service from client via Ksoap.. I am hardcoding the IP address here in the URL..
When ever I switch to a new network I need to change the IP address for the application to work

can anyone share the solution for this please?

Comment: - Set a static IP address in that computer. 
    - Create a DNS pointing to that address

Comment: any examples to refer on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

Select a free [Dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service from e.g. [this list](http://dnslookup.me/dynamic-dns/). You get an adress like `http://myserver.dyndns.org` that you can setup to point to your IP adress. Then replace the hardcoded IP with the new adress.

```
private static final String URL = "http://myserver.dyndns.org/AndroidBackEnd/services/Calculate?wsdl";
```

Dynamic DNS is actually intendet for IP adresses that change very regularly (and it might be required that the IP is updated periodically by these services). If you don't need that look for a regular [DNS hosting service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hosting_service).

Comment: Zapl-- I got an address and I mapped my IP to it... the new url worked on my local network however, it didnt work when I tried from a different internet connection

Comment: Ah you have a local IP. Well then you need to expose the server via portforwarding or whatever possibilities you have to the internet & use your public internet IP for the dns service. So you connect from dns adress to your public IP to local IP.

Answer (score 1):

There can be two ways of going about it.

1. (not very elegant) : Instead of hard coding in the code, take input form the user. This part *`AndroidBackEnd/services/Calculate?wsdl`* will always remain constant, so you just need the IP address of the system which is hosting the web-service and concatenate it with the contant part.  Save a default value in your code and run that when there is no input. Otherwise, connect to the machine whose IP would be entered by the user.
2. (as already suggested by others) : Create your own domain. (Most probably you might need to buy one. There are a few who still provide it for free, but you need to search them out. Or, if you are willing to buy then you can check out http://www.dotster.com/ or http://www.networkSolutions.com). After you have registered your domain, you need to enter the static IP of the system which provides the web-service to make the DNS point to your system.

Comment: I have done the first option.. but I was looking for a better approach :)

Comment: Yeah, then the second one would be a better choice for you.